# NullPointerException on java Mapper with MyBatis

Tags: java, spring, mybatis, mybatis-generator

I'm getting the `NullPointerException` and I can't figure out where are my mistakes.

The error is in `selectByExample` function. The code is:

```
package com.service.test;

@Service 
public class TestService {
[...]
@Autowired
private TestMapper TestMapper;
[...]

public List<Short> test(){
    List<Short> lista = new ArrayList<Short>();

    testExample me = new testExample();
    me.or().andTestEqualTo(1);
    List<test> listTest = TestMapper.selectByExample(me); //line 81

    for(int i=0; i<listTest.size(); i++){
        lista.add(listTest.get(i).getNuovoDb());
    }

    return lista;
}
```

Controller.java

```
    TestService ms = new TestService();
    List<Short> listTest = ms.sediMigrate(); //line 46
```

The applicationContext is the follow:

```
       <!-- enable autowire -->
    <context:annotation-config />
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.service.test"/>
[...]


    <bean class="org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer">
        <property name="basePackage" value="com.test.**"/>
        <property name="sqlSessionFactoryBeanName" value="exSqlSessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
```

Here there is the error:

> [11/07/14 11.19.33:848 CEST] 0000004f servlet       E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper service SRVE0068E:
>   Generata eccezione non rilevata in uno dei metodi di servizio del
>   servlet dispatcher nell'applicazione TestEAR. Creata eccezione:
>   org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613) Caused by:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   com.service.test.TestService.test(TestService.java:81)    at
>   com.test.controller.ReturnPage(controller.java:46)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)     at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     ... 25 more
>
> [11/07/14 11.19.33:856 CEST] 0000004f FfdcProvider  W
>   com.ibm.ws.ffdc.impl.FfdcProvider logIncident FFDC1003I: Emesso evento
>   FFDC in C:\Program
>   Files\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSrv01\logs\ffdc\server1_5e0b5e0b_14.07.11_11.19.33.8537970037945028520402.txt
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest() 309
>   [11/07/14 11.19.33:857 CEST] 0000004f webapp        E
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp logServletError SRVE0293E:
>   [Errore servlet]-[dispatcher]: java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   com.service.test.TestService.test(TestService.java:81)    at
>   com.test.controller.ReturnPage(controller.java:46)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)     at
>   org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
>     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:738)     at
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1657)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:939)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:502)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:181)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:3935)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.handleRequest(WebGroup.java:276)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:931)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1592)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:186)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:452)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:511)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:305)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1613)

Comment: Where does the exception occure?

Comment: I added the information to the question.

Comment: What's at these lines: `TestService.java:81` and `controller.java:46`?

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in this code, which I assume is yours:java.lang.NullPointerException at com.service.test.TestService.test(TestService.java:81) at com.test.controller.ReturnPage(controller.java:46) at

Comment: @kiwiron Yes, I did it. And the selectByExample function returns null, but I don't understand why.

Comment: @cy3er I commented the line in the code upper. The line 81 is: List<test> listTest = TestMapper.selectByExample(me); and the line 46 is the call at the method where it is the line 81.

Comment: We need the complete code - it is impossible to know what TestMapper returns. Also the line private TestMapper TestMapper is bad - if it compiles (does it?), then there would be no way to separate a call to a static method from a call to an instance method. private TestMapper testMapper is the usual syntax.

Comment: @kiwiron added the complete code. The rest of the class is not inherent so I omitted it. I added also the controller line. I changed "TestMapper TestMapper" in "private TestMapper testMapper" and I get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you use Spring you should avoid explicitly creating your beans (using `new` operator) - the framework should do it for you. And the bean instance should be already in Spring context. If you instantiate your service bean with `new` nothing will be autowired. Thats why you will have `null` instead of your mapper instance.

Please look info the Spring documentation about dependency injection and beans lifecycle in Spring applications http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/beans.html#beans-factory-collaborators

**Update:**

Autowiring `TestService` into your controller may solve your issue.

```
@Controller
public class Controller {
    @Autowired private TestService testService;
    ...
    @RequestMapping
    public String returnPage() {
        ...
        testService.sediMigrate(); 
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "avoid explicity creating your beans"?

Comment: selectByExample is generated by MyBatis Generator and it is not static.

Comment: If I understood well, I believe I didn't create the beans for TestService, but I used this line <context:component-scan base-package="com.service.test"/>

Comment: `TestService ms = new TestService();` means you did. I updated my answer.